# Почему сокращение условий WHERE не приводит к ускорению выполнения запроса?

Tags: sql, sql-server, производительность

Поступил запрос с таким условием:

```
  and (c.COL like '@p%'
   or c.COL like '@P%'
   or c.COL like '@р%'
   or c.COL like '@Р%'
   or c.COL like '@C%'
   or c.COL like '@c%'
   or c.COL like '@с%'
   or c.COL like '@С%'
   or c.COL like '@R%'
   or c.COL like '@r%'
   or c.COL like '@p um%'
   or c.COL like '@P um%'
   or c.COL like '@р um%'
   or c.COL like '@Р um%'
   or c.COL like '@kpr%')
```

В текстовом поле COL встречаются в разных регистрах как Р/С русская, так и Р/С английская, поэтому они продублированы. При сокращении условия до такого состояния:

```
and (lower(c.COL) like '@p%'
   or lower(c.COL) like '@р%'
   or lower(c.COL) like '@c%'
   or lower(c.COL) like '@с%'
   or lower(c.COL) like '@r%'
   or Purpose like '@kpr%')
```

запрос выполняется даже дольше. Хотя избыточные like '@p um%' отсутствуют, и в целом альтернативных условий стало меньше. Почему так? Это влияние функции lower()?

Comment: У T-SQL есть две проблемы: (1) условия OR и (2) вызов функции LOWER (). SQL Server обычно настраивается без учета регистра (case-insensitive). Так что нет необходимости в функции LOWER ().

Comment: для того чтобы сравнить скорость выполнения запроса нужно сравнивать планы выполнения

Comment: `.. c.COL like '@p%' .. or c.COL like '@p um%'` - второе условие не имеет смысла, если оно выполняется, то выполняется и первое.

Comment: даже если у вас на колонку COL был индекс, то взятие колонки COL в любую функцию (lower()) делает использование индекса невозможным. Так что такое "усовершенствование" вполне может снизить скорость и в сотни раз, в зависимости от наличия индекса и размера таблицы. Ну или наоборот ускорит, если у вас есть функциональный индекс по lower(COL)

Comment: Спасибо за советы насчёт регистра и индекса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае все условия `LIKE` проверяют начало строки. При этом возможно использование индекса, так как `c.COL like '@P%'` эквивалентно `c.COL >= '@P' and c.COL < '@Q'`.

Во втором случае используется функция от столбца, что делает невозможным использование индекса. Поэтому будет выполнен полный просмотр таблицы.

Поэтому при более-менее большом количестве записей (от нескольких сотен) второй вариант работает дольше.

Возможные выходы:

1. Изменить тип столбца на регистронечувствительный.
2. Построить индекс по `lower(c.COL)`

Comment: Про индекс интересно. Это актуально для всех строковых функций? Где можно почитать?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide